# On Demand List with pagination in Select2 (4.0.3) through web method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a select2 list which having huge data. So, basically on scrolling we're populating data through pagination( adding 10 records on each scroll). In Select2, version 3.4.8, its working fine and able to load data through asp.net web method. Below is the code

```js
$("#ddlEntity").select2({
        width: 200,
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        loadMorePadding: 200
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            var data = { id: ID, text: Value };
            callback(data);
        },
        query: timedelayfunction(function (query) {
            var res = AjaxRequest( URL , 'GetOnDemandWebMethod', { searchFilter : query.term, pageCounter: query.page, uid:$('#uid').val() });
            var data = { more: (res.d[0] != undefined ? res.d[0].MoreStatus : false), results: [] }, i;
            for (i = 0; i < res.d.length; i++) {
                data.results.push({ id: res.d[i].ID, text: res.d[i].Value });
            }
            query.callback(data);
        }, 200)
    });
```

After moving Select2, version 4.0.3, same functionality is breaking. Can anyone help on this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've resolved it at my end and after tweaking web method response as JSON serialised array string and select2 v4 with data portion as json string worked for me.

for others it would be simple as like below code

```js
$('#ddlEntity').select2({
    width: 200,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: {
     id: -1,
     text: "Select any."
    },
    ajax: {
     type:"POST",
     url: '',
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     async: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     data: function (params) {
      return "{'searchFilter':'" + (params.term || "") + "','searchPage':'" + (params.page || 1) + "'}";
     },
     processResults: function (res, params) {
      var jsonData = JSON.parse(res.d);
      params.page = params.page || 1;
      var data = { more: (jsonData[0] != undefined ? jsonData[0].MoreStatus : false), results: [] }, i;
      for (i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
       data.results.push({ id: jsonData[i].ID, text: jsonData[i].Value });
      }
      return {
       results: data.results,
       pagination: {
        more: data.more
       }
      };
     }
    }
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for this JDeb.  I'm working on a project where the data is 300k rows, and attempting to load it into select2 is bogging it down.  I've tried to use your solution, but i'm unable to get it to work.  Does your solution require server side pagination?  I feel like this example is missing something.